# Agrupar y tener el dato con el autoincremento mayor- SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql

Necesito buscar en una base de datos como esta, donde "id" es la variable con autoincremento:

```
id   device 

6      1
5      1
4      2
3      2
2      1
1      1
```

Necesito ordenar por "device" pero me dio cuando "id" es minimo, necesito agrupar con "device" cuando "id" es maximo

Usé:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY device
```

Respuesta que dio:

```
id   device
1      1
3      2
```

Respuesta deseada:

```
id   device
6      1
4      2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haz un `SELECT`de los `id` máximos de tu tabla agrupados por `device` luego de obtener ese `SELECT`, haz otro `SELECT` sobre la misma tabla obteniendo los resultados de un `INNER JOIN` utilizando el primer `SELECT`, donde filtraras los registros por los `id` obtenidos en la primera consulta.

Debe quedarte algo como esto:

```
SELECT A.* FROM `table` A 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM `table` GROUP BY device
    ) B ON A.id = B.id
ORDER BY A.device
```

Comment: Y que vendría siendo la A y B?

Comment: Son etiquetas solamente cada letra representa a una Tabla por así decir.

Comment: Si eso me di cuenta. Lo probé así y funcionó a la perfección, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: De nada amigo, un placer ayudarlos con sus problemas.

Answer (score 1):

**LO QUE HICE**

> Deberías lograrlo usando una función de agregación como `MAX()`
>   aplicada a la columna `id` y después agrupar por `device`quedando de
>   este modo

```
SELECT MAX(id), device from tabla group by device;
```

Lo único que debes sustituir es `tabla` por el nombre de tu tabla

Si lo que deseas es mostrar el resto de las columnas, bastaría con que hagas lo siguiente

```
SELECT MAX(id), device, columna3, columna4, columnaN 
from tabla 
group by device;
```

Donde:

> columna1, columna2, columnaN son los nombres de las columnas que
>   deseas se muestren en el resultado final de tu consulta; basta con que
>   le coloques el nombre que le corresponde a cada uno y los separes por
>   coma

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Si quieres mostrar todas las demás columnas pero no escribirlas una por una; debería verse tu consulta de este modo

```
SELECT MAX(id), device, tabla.* 
from tabla 
group by device;
```

**LO QUE HICE**

Lo importante aqui es `tabla.*` donde tabla es el nombre de tu tabla y al colocar `.*` le estamos indicando que nos traiga todas las columnas

Comment: Funciona bien, pero si son más las columnas, ¿Que puedo hacer?
Algo parecido a *, o algo como eso

Comment: O sea, no solo "id" y "device"

Comment: Aja, que salgan el resto de datos

Comment: Imaginé eso. Pero no existe un forma más general. Sin necesidad de especificar cuales son

Comment: @IvanGonzalez dime te sirvió?

Comment: Lo siento, estaba probando. No me funciona bien, los otros datos no los da correctamente

Comment: Solo el id maximo, los otros datos los da para los id minimos